# How do I check the number of edits I have done on my own posts?

Tags: support, edits

Is there any way to check the number of edits that I have done on my own posts. For example my total number of edits are `503`.

How can I check that how many of them are on my own posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[32](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116005/) as of last dump

Comment: +1 for query and result.

Comment: that's out of date by a month. @AwaisQarni as of now.

Comment: @Sathya dude didn't understand. Are you of the opinion that this stat is 1 month old?

Comment: @Sathya: Did you read my answer?  `as of last dump`

Comment: @AwaisQarni: yes, that's one month old number. There is no way to get the current one

Comment: @Genesis -  `as of last dump` is not clear to those unfamiliar with how the data explorer works/how often the dumps are generated

Answer (score 5):

You can query the Data Explorer with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1929/edits-on-my-posts), but the data will be a few weeks old already.

You can also click on `revisions` under the `activity` tab in your profile and count them by hand.

I imagine there's a way to get it with [the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help), but I don't know the exact syntax you would use.